# Sort a filtered array

Tags: vue.js

I know its .sort(), but I dont know where it goes in the code below. I have tried every way, and it either breaks or doesnt work. I want to sort it in this case alphabetically.

```
<div id="navBar">
  <span v-for="country in countries" :key="country">
    <button v-on:click="setCountry(country)">{{ country }}</button>       
  </span>
</div>

data: {  
selectedCountry: ""
},

computed: {
countries() {
  return [...new Set(this.hotels.map(h => h.country))]
}
},
methods: {
setCountry(country) {
  this.selectedCountry = country === this.selectedCountry
    ? ''
    : country;
  this.selectedRegions = [];
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
computed: {
countries() {
  let arr = [...new Set(this.hotels.map(h => h.country))]
  return arr.sort()
}
```

Also if this does not work, then how does your `[...new Set(this.hotels.map(h => h.country))]` looks like.